# How can I restore the El Capitan Messages notification sound (chime) to the old sound?

Tags: ios, audio, macos, messages

I've noticed when I receive messages in the Messages app in El Capitan, it plays the "Chime" sound from iOS 9.

I recall that in the previous version of OSX, or perhaps the one before it, the incoming Messages notification sound was simply a different pitched variant of the "send" message sound.

How can I restore it to the original Messages sound from the older versions of OSX?

Answer (score 1):

Prefs > General
Take your pick…

[image]

Mine's always just gone 'ping' so I don't know precisely which sound you mean

Comment: Thanks, but I've seen these.  There is a zip file out there with the "old" sounds (I guess Mavericks and before), but placing them into the /System sounds folder requires disabling SIP, and that doesn't seem like a very good thing to do, just to replace a sound.   It's a shame Messages (or OSX) won't just let you use custom .aiff sounds.